# What is the correct way of handling dependencies if back end and front end code is in the same repository?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have got a project where the back end Node.js and the front end Vue.js code is in the same repository.

They share dependencies via `package.json`. There are common dependencies needed for both parts, and there dependencies specific either to the front end part or to the back end part.

**How the project is built and run:**

The front end part is built with:

```
npm install
npm run build
```

After this the front end part is compiled to `dist` folder and then put into a docker image where the server would run it.
The server code and `node_modules` are also put to the same image and then the server is run with:

```
npm run start
```

**Problem:**

Because of the shared dependencies the `node_modules` folder (needed to run the server part) includes the front end dependencies which makes it ridiculously huge. I manged to decrease the size by excluding dev depnedencies via `npm install --only=production`, but I would prefer not having to manage them at all.

**Questions:**

- How to split the server and the client dependencies and reduce the size of the resulting image?
- What is the best practice to run the back end code in such setup? I think it should not require `node_modules` and should include the dependencies just like the front end distribution does. How to achieve this? Is is a recommended way?
- Are there any other concerns in using `node_modules` directly in production?